# Javascript event listening differs depending on use of anonymous or named function

Tags: javascript, events, dom

I'm using the following code to duplicate the input of one textarea in another:

```
/**
 * Copies the values entered into the old description
 * into the new description, until the user focuses 
 * on the new description
 */
var DescriptionLinker = (function() {
    var elOldDescription,
        elNewDescription,
        linkIsBroken;

    this.init = function() {
        console.log('Initializing DescriptionLinker');
        elOldDescription = document.getElementById("old-description");
        elNewDescription = document.getElementById("new-description");
        linkIsBroken = false;

        linkDescriptions();
        watchLinkBreak();
    }

    // Assigns values to 'this'
    var finalize = function() {
        this.elOldDescription = elOldDescription;
        this.elNewDescription = elNewDescription;
    }

    var linkDescriptions = function() {
        elOldDescription.addEventListener("keyup", linkListener(), false);
    }

    var unlinkDescriptions = function() {
        elOldDescription.removeEventListener("keyup", linkListener(), false);
    }

    var linkListener = function(){
        elNewDescription.value = elOldDescription.value;
    }

    var watchLinkBreak = function() {
        console.log("Watching for link break");
        elNewDescription.addEventListener("focus", function(){
            unlinkDescriptions();
        });
    }

    finalize();
    return this;
})();

DescriptionLinker.init();
```

The code works, however the values do not appear in `<textarea id="new-description"></textarea>` until I focus on the text area. If I replace the call to `linkerfunction()` with an identical anonymous function then the values correctly appear in the `new-description` textarea as I type in the `old-description`. Any ideas why?

To clarify, the following works correctly:

```
var linkDescriptions = function() {
    elOldDescription.addEventListener("keyup", function(){ 
         elNewDescription.value = elOldDescription.value;
    }, false);
}
var unlinkDescriptions = function() {
    elOldDescription.removeEventListener("keyup", function(){ 
         elNewDescription.value = elOldDescription.value;
    }, false);
}
```

PS reason for all this is transition from a legacy system :p

Comment: Err, you realise that `DescriptionLinker === window` don't you? And that **all** the properties assigned to *this* in the function are created as properties of the global object? I.e they become global variables? E.g. `typeof window.init == 'function'`.

Comment: Nooooope, did not realize. I know a couple ways to fix this (pun), ie returning a JSON object, but why does `this` refer to the global object? I thought it would be scoped by the anon function..?

Comment: `this` has nothing to do with scope. It is a local variable set by how a function is called or by [*bind*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5). You don't set *this* so it defaults to the global (window in a browser) object, or will be *undefined* in strict mode.

Comment: Okay thanks for pointing this out, realize what I was mistaken about now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course! When you pass a defined function in place of an anonymous function, you omit the `()`, else this function will be called as soon as it is compiled. So, change

```
lOldDescription.addEventListener("keyup", linkListener(), false);
```

To

```
lOldDescription.addEventListener("keyup", linkListener, false);
                                                      ^^ bye bye ()
```